# XML equality problem with Scala

Tags: xml, scala

I've stumbled upon a peculiarity of XML equality in Scala:

```
scala> val x = <a>12</a>
x: scala.xml.Elem = <a>12</a>

scala> val y = <a>{1}2</a>
y: scala.xml.Elem = <a>12</a>

scala> x == y
res0: Boolean = false
```

What I think is happening is that two `xml.Text` objects are being created, and that is different than one. However, this isn't how it works in the XML spec :) and I wonder if there is any way to compare equality so that this would return true.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `<a>12</a>` represents an element with a single child node with the value "12", whereas `<a>{1}2</a>` represents an element with two child nodes, with values "1" and "2", respectively.

They are logically distinguishable in Scala: `x.child` is `ArrayBuffer(12)` whereas `y.child` is `ArrayBuffer(1, 2)`, and therefore they are inequal.

What about the XML spec? By my reading, those two XML objects *are* not equal. According to [the XML spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#NT-content), an element's contents consists of a sequence of one or more things (which DOM calls "nodes"), and those things can be [CharData](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#NT-CharData). Therefore, it is logical for an element to have two adjacent CharData children, and this is considered logically different from a single concatenated CharData child.

If you really want to consider them equal, you should write a normalisation pass that takes an XML object and concatenates any adjacent text nodes, and then perform an equality test.

Comment: How would one represent two separate adjacent Text nodes in XML?

Comment: I think there are possible DOM arrangements that the XML syntax cannot produce? This would appear to be one. Even if the Scala behaviour is valid, combining into a single text node would also appear to be valid, and more useful, I think.

Comment: @aharon There isn't a way to do that in the XML syntax. Note that I carefully didn't mention DOM above (since that isn't the API we are dealing with here). Just going by the XML spec, it allows multiple CharData nodes to be adjacent. That explains why Scala is correct but it doesn't get you what you want. My last paragraph does though.