# Avoiding Scala XML's <a>b {"c"}</a> != <a>b c</a> behaviour in tests

Tags: xml, scala, scalatest

I'm using scalatest and want to say

```
actualXML should be === expectedXML
```

especially as === doesn't care about attribute order. However the assertion fails when text has been embedded using Scala XML's { ... } syntax because

```
scala> <a>b {"c"}</a>.child
res8: scala.xml.Node* = ArrayBuffer(b , c)
```

whereas:

```
scala> <a>b c</a>.child
res9: scala.xml.Node* = ArrayBuffer(b c)
```

I can write a method

```
import scala.xml.Elem
import scala.xml.XML
def launder(xml: Elem): Elem = XML.loadString(xml.toString)
```

giving

```
launder(actualXML) should be === expectedXML
```

but would like to be able to use the vanilla syntax.

Comment: possible duplicate of [XML equality problem with Scala](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5467546/xml-equality-problem-with-scala)

Comment: The http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5467546/xml-equality-problem-with-scala is certainly the cause of my problem. I guess my question really is how to elegantly normalise the XML so the 'should be ===' syntax works.

Comment: Is it only whitespace that is the problem?

Comment: Whitespace is part of it as Scala (XML spec itself) treats whitespace as part of the document. The specific problem with {...} is that it's treated as a separate text item - hence the difference in XML.child ArrayBuffers above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can introduce your own Equalizer class specifically for Xml Elem:

```
class ElemEqualizer(left: scala.xml.Elem) {
  def ===(right: Any) = new Equalizer(launder(left).===(launder(right))
}
implicit def convertToElemEqualizer(left: scala.xml.Elem) = new ElemEqualizer(left)

@Test def foobar(): Unit = {
  val a = <a>b {"c"}</a>
  val b = <a>b c</a>

  assert(a === b)
}
```

So you're introducing another implicit conversion but this time specifically for `Elem`, which compares the laundered Elems.

Comment: `toString` would fail if attributes were in different order.

Comment: @dave no it doesn't: <a foo="1" bar="2">b c</a>.toString == <a bar="2" foo="1">b c</a>.toString returns true

Comment: hm. OP mentioned "especially as === doesn't care about attribute order".  Sure enough, `<a x="1" y="2"/> should be === <a y="2" x="1"/>` passes.  Unfortunately, so does `<a x="1" y="2"/> should be === <a y="2" x="wtf"/>`.  I smell a bug :-(

Comment: I believe that just happens to be the current behavior, [which some would regard as a bug](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-2735), and may change in future versions of Scala.  Unless the spec actually states some guarantees about attribute ordering. Haven't looked though...

Comment: And `toString` does not reorder attributes.  The attribute ordering behavior you're relying on only happens w/ XML literals.  `XML.load(new StringReader("""<x a="1" b="2"/>""")).toString should be === xml.XML.load(new StringReader("""<x b="2" a="1"/>""")).toString` fails.

Comment: Ok, I've removed the references to toString.

Comment: And, FWIW, I did [smell a bug](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-3886), and it was [fixed in Scala 2.9](https://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/changeset/23319).

Comment: So I think that probably means that comparison would work, but as you say we shouldn't rely on it.

Answer (score 1):

See answer above - I now understand the area better. Here's the code with brackets corrected and a test that builds on Matthew and Dave's comments.

My apologies for it's size:

```
// Tested with Scala 2.9.1

import org.junit.Test
import org.scalatest.Assertions._
import org.scalatest.TestFailedException
import scala.xml.Elem
import scala.xml.Node
import scala.xml.XML
import scala.xml.Utility

class TestEquals {

  val a = <a>b {"c"}</a>
  val b = <a>b c</a>

  @Test def defaultBehaviour {
    assert(a === a)
    assert(b === b)

    // _but_ this fails
    intercept[TestFailedException] { assert(a === b) } // i.e. a != b
  }

  // Add class & implicit to improve the behaviour
  class ElemEqualizer(left: Any) {
    private def launder(x: Any): Node = Utility.trim(x match {
      case xml: String => XML.loadString(xml)
      case xml: Elem => XML.loadString(xml.toString)
    })

    def ===(right: Any): Option[String] =
      new Equalizer(launder(left)).===(launder(right))
  }

  implicit def convertToElemEqualizer(left: Elem) = new ElemEqualizer(left)

  // Retest the behaviour with ElemEqualizer available
  @Test def betterBehaviour {
    assert(a === b)
    assert(a === "<a>b c</a>")  // works for 'right' string that's XML - see launder

    intercept[TestFailedException]
      { assert("<a>b c</a>" === a) } // but not this way round

    // attribute order doesn't matter
    assert(<a attr0="123" attr1="456"/> === <a attr1="456" attr0="123"/>)

    // fails if attribute values don't match - that's good
    intercept[TestFailedException]
      { assert(<a attr0="123" attr1="456"/> === <a attr1="456" attr0="xxx"/>) }

    // and again with 'right' as a string
    intercept[TestFailedException]
      { assert(<a attr0="123" attr1="456"/> === XML.loadString("<a attr1='456' attr0='xxx'/>")) }
  }

  @Test def xmlContainingText {
    // Here left and right wouldn't be equal without use of Utility.trim()
    val left = <a>
 <b>text</b>
</a>
    val right = <a><b>text</b></a>
    assert(left === right)
  }

}
```